# Shower Door won’t fit

Tags: shower

We are looking at changing our sliding shower door. We have measured the space and it is 1155mm. All of the doors we can find appear to be 1100 or 1200 and even with the allowance don’t seem to include our size. Do we go big and try and fit in or small?

Comment: With a sliding door I'd imagine there's a fairly good chance you could get the larger one and cut the rails down to size.

Comment: As @brhans states, just cut bottom and top rails to size, and the doors, which overlap anyway, will overlap by an additional 4.5 cm. Just measure the rails carefully -- measure twice, cut once.

Comment: I would bet that the installation instructions for the door give details on how to cut to fit. When I am shopping online I try to pull up the installation instructions to see if installing a given product is something I am up to and want to tackle.

Comment: The down side is that the opening to shower is reduced when rails are cut. In your case it may not be significant. ButI recently worked in a custom built tile shower that used a sliding door that was modified. The opening was reduced to less that 20”.